# How do you add document metadata through the DocuSign UI?

Tags: docusignapi

Can I add hidden metadata on the document level like you can through the API? In the DocuSign API, I can do the following in the document object:

```
    new Document()
    {
        DocumentId = (i+1).ToString(),
        DocumentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(request.Documents[i].Stream.ReadAsBytes()),
        Name = request.Documents[i].Name,
        DocumentFields = new List<NameValue>()
        {
            new NameValue()
            {
                Name = "DocumentType",
                Value = "ElectronicConsent"
            }
        }
    };
```

The `DocumentFields` specifies what *that* document is. Through the API, I can retrieve the document and its field:

```
EnvelopeDocumentsResult docList = envApi.ListDocuments(_accountId, envelopeId);
DocumentFieldsInformation docInfo = envApi.ListDocumentFields(_accountId, envelopeId, document.DocumentId);
```

Since I know what the returned document is, I can now run business logic on it. I'd like to allow users the ability to perform a similar action in the UI. This would allow the API to retrieve an envelope that did *not* originate in code, but the code still knows how to handle that type of document.

I tried the following:

1. I created a "Document Custom Field."
2. The "Document Custom Field" is of type "Drop Down" and contains various known document types.
3. I modify the custom field so that it is white and read only (the signer won't be able to modify it).
4. Before sending the envelope/document, I add this custom field to the form and select the correct document type.
5. I send the document.

When I run the same API method to retrieve "Document Fields," the value doesn't get returned. It appears that manually placing the field on the document results in the field being part of the "form" instead of metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set Document Field as you can set it in an API. The Document Custom Field which you are setting is just another reusable DocuSign tab. So on WEBApp if you are planning to use Document Custom Fields, then your Connect listener should check for two things, one document fields which will be coming from the API, and the Document Custom Field which will be coming as form data. When doing through WebApp, I will make that field white label on white text so that it is not visible to the customer, but it is present on the document. To make maintenance easier on your side, I would create two Connect listener, one just for API user who will be using Document Field, another for non-API/WebApp user who will be using these reusable Document Custom Fields, and write different logic on both listener.

Comment: Thanks Amit. I created a document custom field list of "document types," and I noticed that the value selected is shared across all of the instances of that custom field. For example, on the UI's tab placement page, I have two documents. I placed one of my custom fields on the header of each of the documents and selected the document type. Whenever I change one of the document types (Default Option), the other one automatically changes too. Can I change these values independent of one another?

Comment: Two things are driving this behavior, first your Document Custom Field has a name(datalabel) which is same on both the documents. Second there is a Sending Settings in your Admin, `on all documents in an envelope` under section - `Automatically replicate information in fields with the same Data Label`, With this setting and same datalabel, wherever you will be using the Document Custom Fields (with same datalabel) on an envelope then same value gets replicated. Either you change the setting to `on an individual document` in above section, or which adding Custom Field, rename the datalabel.